# What is the probability of a number from 1-25 being an odd number or a factor of 20?

Tags: probability

What is the probability of a number from 1-25 being an odd number or a factor of 20?
Here's my working out:

> Odd numbers: 12/25 (1, 3, 5, 7, 9, 11, 13, 15, 19, 21, 23, 25)
>
> Factors of 20: 6/25 (1, 2, 4, 5, 10, 20)
>
> Both: 2/25 (1, 5)
>
> P(odd number or factor of 15) = P(odd number) + P(fator of 20) -
>   P(both)
>
> = 12/25 + 6/25 - 2/25 = 16/25

16/25 was too long for MyMaths' input box so I converted it to a decimal:

16 / 25 = 0.64

That was incorrect.

Comment: You just forgot 17. There are 13 odd numbers. But otherwise the reasoning is perfect.

Comment: Listing and counting is a nuisance. Half of the numbers to $24$ are even, and half are odd, so far $12$ odd. And then there is $25$, for a total of $13$.

Answer (score 4):

Thanks to the person who pointed out that I left out the 17. The answer is 0.68. It's always the simple things that I get wrong!

> Odd numbers: 13/25 (1, 3, 5, 7, 9, 11, 13, 15, 17, 19, 21, 23, 25)
>
> Factors of 20: 6/25 (1, 2, 4, 5, 10, 20)
>
> Both: 2/25 (1, 5)
>
> P(odd number or factor of 15) = P(odd number) + P(factor of 20) -
>   P(both)
>
> = 13/25 + 6/25 - 2/25 = 17/25 17 / 25 = 0.68